# PC doesn't boot without slow mode booting enabled

Tags: windows-10, boot, bsod, windows-installer

A couple of days back my PC died and now I'm stuck with a weird problem.
Here's what happened:

I was on my PC listening to some music. All of a sudden my mouse froze. I have a problem with my Razer Synapse where I have to reconnect my mouse in order for it to work again. So, I thought "Oh well, no big deal!" Then, I got a BSOD. I've had a couple of minor BSOD's in the past, some driver-related. I tried to reboot; no luck.

After hours of checking cables, resetting my BIOD and all the basic stuff, I found a little switch on my motherboard, called slow mode booting switch.

I switched that on, and guess what happens: my PC boots perfectly fine. The problem is I can't do much when in slow mode booting because it drops the CPU freq. or something. How I experience this is 10fps on League of Legends instead of the usual 250+.

From this point on, I've had no clue what to do, so I hoped you guys could help me out on this one.

Here are my specs:

- Intel i7 6700K 4 GHz
- 2x hyper X 8 GB DDR4 RAM
- MSI Z170A GAMING M5
- MSI GeForce GTX 970 4G
- Samsung SSD; 250 GB

If you guys need anything else, please tell me. I'm not so sure what for information to give you guys.

**EDIT 1:**
The BSOD was CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT

**EDIT 2:**
The slow mode booting switch on my motherboard:

[image: SLOW_1: Slow Mode Booting Switch (taken from the manual)]

**TLDR:** Can boot perfectally fine when slow boot mode enabled. If slow boot mode is set to default I end up getting a black screen with a flickering underscore.

Comment: There are four BSODs with the word "watchdog": CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT, DPC_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT, DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION, WIN32K_POWER_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT

Comment: This page is suggestive: https://service.msicomputer.com/msi_user/support/TechFAQdetail.aspx?formid=3265 Bearing that in mind, have checked your computer's cooling hardware? Are they in perfect working order?

Comment: As far as i can tell they are, everything is spinning and reacting when the pc gets warmer. And like i said in my post, if i set the switch to default i cant boot my pc at all.

Comment: Obvious question, but is the motherboard still under warranty?